# sum time in sql server when duration is in float type

Tags: sql-server, time, sum

```
select dbo.to_hour(SUM(6666.008888))
```

Above select statement gives duration as- *h 6m (to_hour function takes int only but my duration column is of `FLOAT` datatype).

But I want `time as -111h 1m`

Kindly tell how to convert it

Comment: Have a look at the modulo operator: `%60`

Answer (score 1):

Try this Answer:

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST((6666.008888)/60 AS VARCHAR),CHARINDEX('.',CAST((6666.008888)/60 AS VARCHAR))-1) + 'h'
    +' '+SUBSTRING(CAST((6666.008888)/60 AS VARCHAR),CHARINDEX('.',CAST((6666.008888)/60 AS VARCHAR))+1,1) + 'm'
```

***OR***

```
DECLARE @Value NUMERIC(15,8)=6666.008888

SELECT LEFT(CAST((@Value)/60 AS VARCHAR),CHARINDEX('.',CAST((@Value)/60 AS VARCHAR))-1) + 'h'
    +' '+SUBSTRING(CAST((@Value)/60 AS VARCHAR),CHARINDEX('.',CAST((@Value)/60 AS VARCHAR))+1,1) + 'm'
```

**OutPut:**

```
111h 1m
```